# How do I use devicemapper in a Linux container

Tags: linux-containers, device-mapper

I would like to run some software ([paradux](https://github.com/paradux/paradux)) that uses devicemapper inside a Linux container started with `systemd-nspawn`. How do I get devicemapper (specifically via `cryptsetup` and LUKS) to work in the container?

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to give you complete instructions you could follow. What happens if you try?

Comment: I am getting an error message that says I don't have the kernel module. However, I do :-) because it works just fine on the host that runs the container.

Comment: If the failing command is not something big, you could try running it under `strace -f`, see what exactly failed. But most likely it is trying to access `/dev/mapper/control`, which is not there. If you want the container to control the host's mapper, you may have to give it access to the host's `/dev/` directory, e.g. with `mount --bind`

Comment: Makes the container kinda pointless though. Does it have to be nspawn? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am running a different distro in the container.